# Saving (and opening up) a list of png plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save a list of plots with a .png extentions. I can save them individually as a loop.

```
a <- data.frame(x=sample(10))
b <- data.frame(x=sample(10))
c <- data.frame(x=sample(10))

data<-list()
data[[1]] <- a
data[[2]] <- b
data[[3]] <- c


for(i in 1:3)
{
  temp_plot <- ggplot(data[[i]]) + 
    theme_bw() +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=x))
  
  ggsave(temp_plot, file=paste0("plot_", i,".png"), width = 14, height = 10, units = "cm") 
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I save them as a list instead?
2. How do I open them up as a list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save them in a list, yes — for example, using `lapply`:

```
plots = lapply(data, \(x) ggplot(x) + theme_bw() + geom_histogram(aes(x = x)))
```

(pre R 4.1.0, you need to replace `\(x)` with `function (x)`.)

By “open” I assume you mean how to plot them? Well, using `plot`:

```
plot(plots[[2L]])
```

… or implicitly:

```
plots[[2L]]
```

Comment: Thanks. By opening up I mean uploading it them into my global environment.

Comment: Hmm. “upload” exclusively refers to network transfer from a client to a server. So I’m not sure what you mean. Do you mean assigning them to separate variables? You can of course perform regular assignment: `my_first_plot = plots[[1L]]`. But I’m guessing you mean something else?